# Testing Rate Limiting in Karate Framework: Simulating "429 Too Many Requests" Response after 10 POST Requests instead of "201 Created"

Tags: testing, automation, frameworks, karate

How can I use the Karate framework to simulate a scenario where I send 10 POST requests to an API, and after the 10th request, instead of receiving a "201 Created" response, I receive a "429 Too Many Requests" response? This is to test the API's rate limiting functionality.

To achieve so I have tried to use retry in Karate

```
Scenario: Name
    * def requestbody = read('../Data/data.json')
    * def expectedresponsebody = read('../Data/Responsedata.json')
    * header Accept = 'application/json'
    Given url apiurl
    And path pathurl
    And print requestbody
    And request requestbody
    * configure retry = {count: 10, interval:3000}
    When method post
    Then status 429
    And print response
    And match karate.response.header('Content-Type') contains 'application/json'
    And match response == expectedresponsebody
```

The configure retry is getting passed. But the script is not passing as Then status is not 429 as it is not retry 10 times

Answer (score 0):

Karate is not designed for this, especially the `retry until` syntax. My personal opinion is that trying to write and maintain this test is a waste of time.

If you are lucky, this might work: write a loop that makes the call 10 times, and then assert for a 429 when you make one more call.

Instead Karate's [performance-test capability](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling) is what is recommended. Once you understand the Gatling syntax, you may be able to script this particular scenario.

If you really insist on implementing this scenario, write some Java code that uses an [`Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) or something like that. Karate is not the right choice.